# Mutate a shared mutable variable in multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, rust

I want to change a mutable variable in multiple threads. I know this would not be thread-safe, but I want to know how the Rust compiler will deal with it. So I use a range's `map` function to spawn sub-threads:

```
use std::thread;

fn break_law(value: &mut i32) {
    *value += 20;
}

fn main() {
    let mut x = 10;

    let handles = (0..10).map(|| {
        thread::spawn(move || {
        break_law(&mut x);
        println!("{:?}", x);
        })
    }).collect();

    for h in handles {
        h.join().unwrap();
    }
}
```

But I get an error:

```
break_law1.rs:10:24: 15:4 error: type mismatch: the type `[closure@break_law1.rs
:10:28: 15:3 x:_]` implements the trait `core::ops::FnMut<()>`, but the trait `c
ore::ops::FnMut<(_,)>` is required (expected tuple, found ()) [E0281]
break_law1.rs:10        let handles = (0..10).map(|| {
break_law1.rs:11                thread::spawn(move || {
break_law1.rs:12                        break_law(&mut x);
break_law1.rs:13                        println!("{:?}", x);
break_law1.rs:14                })
break_law1.rs:15        }).collect();
break_law1.rs:10:24: 15:4 help: run `rustc --explain E0281` to see a detailed ex
planation
break_law1.rs:10:24: 15:4 error: type mismatch: the type `[closure@break_law1.rs
:10:28: 15:3 x:_]` implements the trait `core::ops::FnOnce<()>`, but the trait `
core::ops::FnOnce<(_,)>` is required (expected tuple, found ()) [E0281]
break_law1.rs:10        let handles = (0..10).map(|| {
break_law1.rs:11                thread::spawn(move || {
break_law1.rs:12                        break_law(&mut x);
break_law1.rs:13                        println!("{:?}", x);
break_law1.rs:14                })
break_law1.rs:15        }).collect();
break_law1.rs:10:24: 15:4 help: run `rustc --explain E0281` to see a detailed ex
planation
break_law1.rs:15:5: 15:14 error: type mismatch: the type `[closure@break_law1.rs
:10:28: 15:3 x:_]` implements the trait `core::ops::FnMut<()>`, but the trait `c
ore::ops::FnMut<(_,)>` is required (expected tuple, found ()) [E0281]
break_law1.rs:15        }).collect();
                           ^~~~~~~~~
break_law1.rs:15:5: 15:14 help: run `rustc --explain E0281` to see a detailed ex
planation
break_law1.rs:18:6: 18:14 error: the type of this value must be known in this co
ntext
break_law1.rs:18            h.join().unwrap();
                            ^~~~~~~~
break_law1.rs:17:2: 19:3 note: in this expansion of for loop expansion
error: aborting due to 4 previous errors
```

According to the info above, I get that range's `map` function definition is like this:

```
// Creates a new iterator that will apply the specified function to each
// element returned by the first, yielding the mapped element instead.
fn map<B, F>(self, f: F) -> Map<Self, F> 
    where F: FnMut(Self::Item) -> B
```

This looks odd, but how should I correct this? And why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type signature of `map` is saying it takes type parameter (`F`) that is a closure (`FnMut`) that *gets passed one argument* that is the type the iterator yields (`(Self::Item)`) and returns a `B` (`-> B`). The piece you're missing is the argument: it needs to be `.map(|x| { ... })` instead of `.map(|| { ... })`.

If you don't care about the value of the argument, you can write `.map(|_| { ... })`, using the `_` pattern to ignore it, or `.map(|_i| { ... })`, where the leading `_` is a convention to indicate that a variable is meant to be unused (it silences the compiler's normal warnings about unused variables).

FWIW, the error message is kinda long, but it does include this info:

```
type mismatch: the type `[closure@break_law1.rs:10:28: 15:3 x:_]` implement
    the trait `core::ops::FnMut<()>`, 
but the trait `core::ops::FnMut<(_,)>` is required
```

I've put line breaks to highlight the difference: the compiler is complaining that the closure you're passing to `map` takes no arguments (`FnMut<()>`), when it actually wants one that takes one (`FnMut<(_,)>`, the `_` indicates a type parameter that hasn't got enough info to fully inferred yet).

Comment: It does work.Thanks. This function signature is really different, by contrast with c++. By the way, just like @swizard says, each thread receives a copy of  variable x, so x in outer scope does not mutate.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, even after fixing parameters number issue as shown above, you will not get the behavior you wanted. The code will compile successfully because each thread will receive a **copy** of variable `x`, as long as integral types in Rust implements `Copy` trait.

I suppose the right example should look like this:

```
fn break_law(value: &mut i32) {
    *value += 20;
}

fn main() {
    let mut x = 10;
    let ref_x = &mut x;

    let handles: Vec<_> = (0..10).map(|_| {
        thread::spawn(move || {
            break_law(ref_x);
            println!("{:?}", x);
        })
    }).collect();

    for h in handles {
        h.join().unwrap();
    }
}
```

Comment: This modification triggers an compiling error: `x` does not live long enough. But I think `x` should have a longer lifetime than `ref_x`, until the last bracket.

Comment: @AselanDu I think the issue you are seeing with that compiler error is that the thread created with `spawn` may potentially outlive the scope it was generated inside of. That means everything referenced from it must have a `'static` lifetime. Since x will be dropped at the end of `main`, `ref_x` cannot have a `'static` lifetime.